# Granting 1 point to opponent after saying GO

Tags: cribbage

In Cribbage play, people tell me that the rule for granting an opponent one point when you say "Go" has been done away with in tournament play. Is this true?

Comment: Everyone who marked this as a duplicate needs to learn to read! The (apparent) duplicate is about "what is Go?", whereas this question asks "has Go been removed from tournament play?" They are completely different questions!